# Uniformly Continuous and bounded function

Tags: real-analysis

Let f be a uniformly continuous and bounded real-value function in $\left [0, \infty  \right )$. We can conclude that exists $\max_{x\in\left [0, \infty  \right )}f\left ( x \right )$. Prove it or give de a cunterexample.
Idea:
In a way, the functions that meet this condition are the Lipchtiz functions, but I don't know how to guarantee that there will always be a maximum in this interval.

Comment: What does that condition have to do with being Lipschitz?

Answer (score 4):

It's not true. Consider $f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$.